# Newbie Programmer Q: What to Add so that Code can Output?

Tags: python-2.7

I ran the code below in my Jupyter notebook, and it all went well, except I am not getting any output. I think I am missing something pretty basic, but not sure what.Here is the code ( not mine, provided by a friend). It compiles, but produces no output. My apologies if I am violating protocol, I tried to follow instructions:

EDIT: My apologies, I have spent a lot of time trying to align a few of the lines of code, but it keeps jumping around. Could someone please suggest something to align ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.usatoday.com/sports/mlb/salaries/"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)

name = []
team = []
pos = []
salary = []
years = []
value = []
annual = []


for row in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    col = row.find_all('td')
    column_1 = col[1].string.strip()
    name.append(column_1)
    column_2 = col[2].string.strip()
    team.append(column_2)
    column_3 = col[3].string.strip()
    pos.append(column_3)
    column_4 = col[4].string.strip()
    salary.append(column_4)
    column_5 = col[5].string.strip()
    years.append(column_5)
    column_6 = col[6].string.strip()
    value.append(column_6)
    column_7 = col[7].string.strip()
    annual.append(column_7)

columns = {
    "name": name,
    "team": team, 
    "pos": pos, 
    "salary": salary, 
    "years": years, 
    "value": value,
    "annual": annual
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(columns)

df.to_csv("somefilename.csv",index = False)
```

Comment: *I wrote the code* and *(not mine, provided by a friend)* are opposites. The code you've posted would (if properly formatted so it would compile) write output to a file, not the screen.

Comment: What are you expecting as output? You should see a new file named "some filename".

Comment: @calico_ , I am hoping to get the data as a .csv file in Excel, or some other program.

Comment: And did you see a new file called "somefilename" after running the script?

Comment: @calico: No. I created a file "somefilename" in Excel , but saw no output.

Comment: @Ken White: Yes, I used shorthand, did not think most would care about the details; I just edited.

Comment: @KenWhite: I spent some 15 minutes trying to align, but it would always missed a line. I did not know what to do about it. Any suggestion?

Comment: You're not reading what we're writing. You don't *create a file* in Excel. The code creates a file and writes to it. Do you have any concept of what the code does at all? You clearly didn't write it. You should ask the friend who gave it to you to explain it. As far as formatting, copy the code (properly formatted) in your editor. Edit your question here, paste in the code, select it all (the code), and hit Ctrl+K on your keyboard (or click the *{}* button on the toolbar).

Comment: @KenWhite: a little, I am trying to teach myself. The code scrapes data from a website into a .csv format using Python's  data frames.

Comment: And how is that the file created by the code can be exported into some other file in .csv format?

Comment: I fixed the code formatting, tried to run it but the server refuses the ssl communication. Do you have any idea if this code works?

Comment: @calico_ Thanks. I ran it in Anaconda and it compiled; at least it did not give me any error message.

Comment: The data is a comma-separated format, it just lacks the extension in the filename that signals other programs what type it is. You can just add .csv to the filename. But, honestly if that is confusing to you, you are way over your head with this...

Comment: @calico_ maybe so. How/where should I add .csv to the filename? Thanks for your patience; I am obviously groking. I went to other sites and they recommended I post here.

Comment: @KenWhite: Is what I wrote correct? The code takes data from a webpage , in html format/data type and outputs data in .csv format using Python's dataframe as a data structure. I am just not clear on how I export the file created by the program into Excel. any suggestions?

Comment: You don't *export it to Excel* Excel will open a CSV file directly.

Comment: @KenWhite: Thanks, good karma for you too for helping a dumb newbie :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "somefilename" in this line:

```
df.to_csv("somefilename",index = False)
```

To the filename you would prefer along with an extension so that Excel knows what to do:

```
df.to_csv("salarydata.csv",index = False)
```

Comment: Sorry, they are closing my school lab, will get back to you when i get back home. Thanks again.